# jQuery .focus() not working in Android webview

Tags: android, jquery, android-webview

I am trying to focus the input field on page loaded, so I used `$(selector).focus()` after the content loaded. It working on desktop and chrome browser in Android, but when I load the same page in a webview in Android, it's not working.

I googled about this focus issue, I found couple attributes for webview so I added them, but still it's not working

```xml
<WebView
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />
```

**Note**: The webview is inside a bottom sheet fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
webview.getsettings().setjavascriptenabled(true);
```

update

```
//add this before you webview load url
webview.requestFocus();
```

Comment: I have already enabled javascript but still not working.

Comment: try webView.requestFocus() before webView.loadUrl(), and do not request other focus after that.